# Update a column only when having a different value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Update table1 set Name='Deepak' where id=1 and Name !='Deepak'
```

Does adding a condition on name column improves the performance considering that id has clustered index and Name has non clustered and there is around 60% probability of getting '0 rows updated' message after running the above query.

Comment: IMO: If you logically think about it yes.  I/O to update a record will be slower than the initial read.  In both cases it has to find the record to update so that's a wash.  So by avoiding the write when not needed, you're saving that I/O time.  Furthermore if there are indexes on that column, then those indexes have to be refreshed based on the new value.

Comment: @xQbert Why sql server doesn't do it automatically if it is more performant?

Comment: I'd have to develop /run some testing to KNOW for certain that it does not (again that was an opinion based on a logical analysis, not a proof).  As I'm not a product owner just a user I wouldn't' be able to answer why they don't if it is more efficient.  It may also depend on version.  earlier versions of SQL may not have, newer versions may...  The only way to know would be to dig deep into documentation or develop your own test and look at the execution plans.  tSQL SQL Server is a broad base of versions and patches!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114360/update-performance-where-no-data-changes  Looks like someone has already done the analysis !  and based on the fact that logging will occur and other "overhead" if the update proceeds even if unchanged data; my initial opinion remains unchanged.  as to why MSFT doens't do it by default... you'd have to ask them.  but logically: if they did this check EVERY time for every update for all columns ... think about the overhead of checking every time.  *shrug*

Comment: @DeepakMishra Because when writing optimisations/execution paths, there are more considerations than just the most simple use case. What if there was a trigger on the table, and someone executing the code wanted to invoke the trigger on that row without changing the value? This would then require some other syntax to override the optimisation, but this is counter intuitive - if you want to stop rows being updated you should be explicit about it, as the inverse (without the where clause) is already being explicit that you want to update the row regardless of if the value is different

Comment: @xQbert Is it a best practice to first select the row and then update on only the changed columns on that row? I have recently found this pattern used in one of the applications I am working on, they first do a read on the row, and then they do the update on changed columns, but in this process they make two round trips to db, Is it wise to write such code?

Comment: No silver bullet. There are pros and cons to both approaches. The term best practice applied in this manner doesn't make sense to me. It's best practice to dispose of objects once you're done with them so GC can clean up and you don't have a memory leak. This is more of a design pattern/approach and not a "best practice" Why the concern?  I'm a big fan of knowing what's right thing to do Black/white cut out as much gray as I can.  However, in this case the gray exists to offer flexibility in the design.  Maybe it's ultra important to log all changes... so update when same makes sense...

Comment: If you update a row and set a value, SQL Server would and *should* update it, whether the value is identical to the existing or not; it's not for the server to control, it's 100% down to your query logic and there are many reason why you might want to update a value to be the same - as mentioned to fire a trigger to test business logic, to insert a row in a system versioning table, to test repeatable code and analyse data thruput etc...

Comment: @Stu The fact is that SQL Server does not actually do any physical writes, unless you are in `SNAPSHOT` isolation (when it needs to update the `rowversion`). You can actually see this if you examine the query plan carefully. The rows obviously present themselves in any triggers and the `@@rowcount` is the same

Comment: @DeepakMishra No it is not best practice to select then update. In *certain* circumstances it may be useful to do it with a `UPDLOCK` hint (similar to `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in some other systems), this would mainly be used to avoid deadlocks, and would only be done if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface - I *thought* that it would mark the page as dirty which would mean it would be flushed to disk on the next checkpoint - is that an incorrect assumption - I have never tested.

Comment: @Stu Correct they are not dirtied or checkpointed. Relevant article from Paul White https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/the-impact-of-non-updating-updates.html. Other cases of dirtying include updating LOB columns >8kb, or clustering columns (because updating the clustering key is effectively a delete and insert)

Comment: @Stu I suggest we move this to [dba.se] where Paul White can answer this himself

Comment: @Charlieface I have identified this pattern in one of the applications I am working on, they first select the row on the primary key, then they analyze it in backend to find out which columns do not have the same values, and then they send the delta update to db again. I don't like this practice, why two round trips to db, why not let the db to figure out and optimize this operation. Also, because there are around 50 columns in that table, it is very rare to find out that there is nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

### Reasons to Only Update If Different

- Reduced locks
- Prevents unnecessary activity if you have triggers or certain configs of SQL Server Replication
- Preserve audit trail columns like LastModifiedDateTime

### Only Update If Different Using EXCEPT

Most people's main complaint would probably be extra query complexity, but I find using EXCEPT makes this process super easy. EXCEPT is ideal because it handles any data type and NULL values without issue

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = @NewVal1
,Col2 = @NewVal2
....
,LastModifiedBy = @UserID
,LastModifiedDateTime = GETDATE()
WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT Col1,Col2
                EXCEPT
                SELECT @NewVal1,@NewVal2
            )
```

Comment: If no of columns are around 50, I guess getting no update situation would be very rare. (1/2^50)